# Execute a stage in DevOps Release pipeline every night on scheduler

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, monitoring, devops, pipeline

I have an Azure DevOps CI Build and Release pipeline in following setup:

- CI Build runs with each new commit in `develop` branch and creates a Build Drop (Artifact)
- Release pipeline runs with each new Artifact and deploys to INT and eventually to PROD (after manual approval)

**I would like to add a 3rd stage (called eg. MONITOR) which would run after the PROD release every night** using the same drop as the PROD stage used, with following schema:

`[Build Drop] -> [INT] -> manual approval: [PROD] -> nightly scheduler: [MONITOR]`

**This seems to be impossible to me, do you know how to achieve this goal?**

Following is crucial for me:

- the MONITOR and PROD run always from exactly the same Artifact
- MONITOR is executed only if the PROD was successful
- if there is a newer PROD release, the old MONITOR is not executed any more and instead the newest one is executed using the newest Artifact which made it to PROD

I tried so far following:

- merge `develop` to `master` when the commit made it to PROD. And then used scheduled nightly Build from `master` with MONITOR stage - it works, but MONITOR uses different Artifact than PROD, so not usable for me
- used scheduled trigger for MONITOR after PROD - does not work, the MONITOR is executed only once at scheduled time and never again
- created extra release pipeline based on **specific Artifact version** with a scheduled trigger - this works, but I have to maintain the specific Artifact version manually with each successful PROD release. Another caveat is that I have to use 2 separate pipelines which makes the overview not so nice. (but, so far the best solution I achieved)

do you have better ideas? many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is have 2 separate Release Pipelines.

[image]

[image]
[image]

This allows you to schedule the release without producing a new artifact (scheduled build).

Then, I would do some of what @Soccerjoshj07 suggested in that I would invoke the REST api in a task on the MONITOR pipeline/stage.

I would make the REST api call to the [Releases](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) endpoint to get the `top=1` releases for `releasedefinitionid=x`. Then use the [Release Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) endpoint to get the PROD environment for that latest release id. With the environment in hand, check the status for `succeeded`. If not, fail the release.

### Edit as per new requirement outlined in comment

Given `PROD.1` is **succeeded** and `PROD.2` is **failed** when `MONITOR` is triggered, then the artifact from `PROD.1` should be used for `MONITOR`.

With this criteria I would change some things. Rather than have the `MONITOR` go digging for the latest `PROD` release and fail if the latest is failed, I would make the **successful** PROD stage tag its build artifact and employ [artifact filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops#release-triggers) on the Monitor pipeline.

The tagging can occur via the [REST api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/tags/add%20build%20tag?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) or using the Tag Build or Release Task from [Colin's ALM Corner Build & Release Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=colinsalmcorner.colinsalmcorner-buildtasks&targetId=e96b5f9a-fd37-48e4-9862-8cf9857f02e9&utm_source=vstsproduct&utm_medium=ExtHubManageList) and might look like this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks, this is interesting approach. I see one caveat - it would run only in case the last PROD deployment was successful. But similar approach could work - the PROD stage, if successful, would per API set the Drop version to FOO Monitor. This way the FOO Monitor would always use latest successful PROD Drop.

Comment: Your question does not specify given `PROD.1` is successful and `PROD.2` is failed when `MONITOR` trigger schedule is elapsed `MONITOR` should run using the artifact from `PROD.1`.

Comment: I see, yep, you are right. Your 2nd suggestion is excellent, exactly what we need! That is a better solution than doing API call for the pipelines. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a YAML template, and if so have you played with the cron schedules? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#scheduled-triggers

If using classic Release UI, I think you can have the definition trigger be on a schedule but that would queue the entire definition. You might have to get creative with variables and maybe create 'isScheduled=true' and use that to determine if it should skip tasks.

Other ideas:
Create a logic app or function app that calls the REST API?  Sample app and github link here: https://oshamrai.wordpress.com/2019/04/22/azure-devops-rest-api-19-queue-builds-and-download-build-results/

The Azure-Devops AZ CLI extension might be easier, though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-devops/pipelines/build?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-devops-az-pipelines-build-queue

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! We are using both YAML and UI, not sure which one is better now. If I am correct, the crons can as well start only the entire definition, is that right? So in that case I would need to use the variables to skip INT and PROD if scheduled. I think this would work, nice approach. I see there as well another alternative - using a never-ending-Powershell-Monitor-Task (which would sleep 24hours and do the stuff, and repeat), but this prevents using standard Tasks in Monitor..

Answer (score 0):

Beside setting up two release pipelines, if you want to use scheduled trigger for only one Stage, I am afraid there is no such out of box way to achieve that, scheduled trigger is only for entire pipeline.

As a workaround, you can add a [custom condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?tabs=yaml&view=azure-devops#run-if-the-build-is-scheduled-even-if-failing-even-if-canceled) for the job of `MONITOR` stage.

For example in yaml:

```
- stage: MONITOR
   jobs:      
   - job:
     condition: and(always(), eq(variables['Release.Reason'], 'Schedule'))
     steps:
```

In UI , you can set this in `Run this job` of agent job:

[image]

In this case, the stage only executed when the release triggered by scheduled trigger. If the release is triggered by other reasons, the `MONITOR` stage will be skipped .

The limitation of this workaround is that when your pipeline is triggered by a scheduled trigger, two other stages are also executed.

Or write a script with `powershell` task (in INT/PROD stages) to determine whether `Release.Reason` is `Schedule`. If yes , skip the current stage.

For how to obtain the latest artifact version of `PROD` and determine the deployment status of `PROD`, you can refer to the two answers above.

Comment: Skipping INT and PROD is a workable solution if the OP is okay with all the extra releases. Good point.

Comment: If I want to set up two different schedules, one nightly that runs stage `A` and one bi-weekly that runs stage `B` there wouldn't be a simple way of achieveing that in the same .yml file?